# Setting last digit of a number to a variable in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, variables, pipe

I have a number `2014061200` and I am trying to extract the one's digit of this number (`0`) and set it to a variable `$STR`, so that `$STR` would equal `0`, because that is in the one's place of the above number.

I made a shell script showing the following:

```
$NUM=2014061200
$STR= $NUM | tail -c 2
echo $STR
```

However when I do this I get a blank for `$STR` instead of the expected result of 0.  I mean when I type

`echo $NUM | tail -c 2`, I do get the output of 0, but how do I get this into a variable?

Thanks

Comment: Please format your code.

Answer (score 5):

Use parameter expansion:

```
num=2014061200
last=${num: -1}
```

`-1` tells bash to extract one character from the right.

Comment: Worth pointing out that the embedded space in that expansion **is** important when using a negative offset. Either that or `${num:(-1)}`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another variation using parameter expansion where `${#num}-1` is the length of the string less 1 and `${num:position:length}` is a substring expression:

```
${num:(${#num}-1):1}
```